# Last batch never uploads to Solr when uploading batches of data from json file stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, solr, batch-processing

This might be a long shot but I might as well try here. There is a block of c# code that is rebuilding a solr core. The steps are as follows:

1. Delete all the existing documents
2. Get the core entities
3. Split the entities into batches of 1000
4. Spin of threads to preform the next set of processes:
5. Serialize each batch to json and writing the json to a file on the server 
   hosting the core
6. Send a command to the core to upload that file using System.Net.WebClient    solrurl/corename/update/json?stream.file=myfile.json&stream.contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8
7. Delete the file.  I've also tried deleting the files after all the batches are done, as well as not deleting the files at all
8. After all batches are done it commits.  I've also tried committing
   after each batch is done.

My problem is the last batch will not upload if it's much less than the batch size.  It flows through like the command was called but nothing happens. It throws no exceptions and I see no errors in the solr logs.  My questions are Why? and How can I ensure the last batch always gets uploaded?  We think it's a timing issue, but we've added Thread.Sleep(30000) in many parts of the code to test that theory and it still happens.

The only time it doesn't happen is:

- if the batch is full or almost full
- we don't run multiple threads it
- we put a break point at the File.Delete line on the last batch and wait for 30 seconds or so, then continue

Here is the code for writing the file and calling the update command.  This is called for each batch.

```
    private const string
        FileUpdateCommand = "{1}/update/json?stream.file={0}&stream.contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8",
        SolrFilesDir = @"\\MYSERVER\SolrFiles",
        SolrFileNameFormat = SolrFilesDir + @"\{0}-{1}.json",
        _solrUrl = "http://MYSERVER:8983/solr/",
        CoreName = "MyCore";

    public void UpdateCoreByFile(List<CoreModel> items)
    {
        if (items.Count == 0)
            return;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc };
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(SolrFilesDir);
        if (!dir.Exists)
            dir.Create();
        var filename = string.Format(SolrFileNameFormat, Guid.NewGuid(), CoreName);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, settings));
        }

        var file = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename);
        var command = string.Format(FileUpdateCommand, file, CoreName);

        using (var client = _clientFactory.GetClient())//System.Net.WebClient
        {
            client.DownloadData(new Uri(_solrUrl + command));
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(30000);//doesn't work if I add this
        File.Delete(filename);//works here if add breakpoint and wait 30 sec or so
    }
```

I'm just trying to figure out why this is happening and how to address it.  I hope this makes sense, and I have provided enough information and code. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since changing the size of the data set and adding a breakpoint "fixes" it, this is most certainly a race condition. Since you haven't added the code that actually indexes the content, it's impossible to say what the issue *really* is, but my guess is that the last commit happens before all the threads have finished, and only works when *all* threads are done (if you sleep the threads, the issue will still be there, since all threads sleep for the same time).

The easy fix - use `commitWithin` instead, and never issue explicit commits. The `commitWithin` parmaeter makes sure that the documents become available in the index within the given time frame (given as milliseconds). To make sure that the documents you submit becomes available within ten seconds, append `&commitWithin=10000` to your URL.

If there's already documents pending a commit, the documents added will be committed before the ten seconds has ellapsed, but even if there's just one last document being submitted as the last batch, it'll never be more than ten seconds before it becomes visible (.. and there will be no documents left forever in a non-committed limbo).

That way you won't have to keep your threads synchronized or issue a final commit, as long as you wait until all threads have finished before exiting your application (if it's an application that actually terminates).

Comment: The commit within was interesting and might help someone else with a similar issue; however, it was not the solution.  We found the issue, and it was outside of the code I pasted.  Appreciate the input!

Comment: What was the issue? It might be helpful as a hint for anyone else stumbling upon the post later.

Comment: We had to call task.Wait() before we committed!